# how to jump with ctags and not to change the PWD in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim, ctags

I used ctags + vim-project in macvim, and the project config like that

```
src=/user/home/src CD = . filter="*.cpp *.h"{
   xxx.cpp
   xxx.h
}
```

so when I open the xxx.cpp,then PWD set to the path of the /user/home/src ,and I make the project's tags file with ctags in the path of  /user/home/src ,so I can load the tags file anywhere in the project.
but in macvim when I jump with ctags to a file in another path p1, the PWD changed to p1, and I can't jump where ctags again!
I want to ask how to config the macvim, when I jump to another file with ctags , the PWD not changed?? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: do you have `set autochdir` in your `.vimrc`? remove/comment it and try again.

Comment: By the way, since you use ctags + project plugin, I suggest you to try Indexer ( http://goo.gl/82waK ) - it is designed to work together with project plugin. It provides painless automatic tags generation and keeps tags up-to-date.